# how to get coefficient in a Fourier series in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am just wondering how to get the coefficient in the circle? is it by matching of coefficient? if so, could someone show how to get that $a_n$ coefficient?

[image]

I was taught the formula of the coefficient of $a_n$ is $\frac{2}{L} \int_{0}^{L} f(x) cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) \,dx$ where L is half of the period.

Could somehow show how to get that $a_n$ coefficient?

Comment: Check again your sources, your formula should only apply if $f$ is an even function and you compute its cosine series. For general Fourier you need to integrate over the full period. // You are missing an $x$ in the cosine.

Comment: Semi-answer: The formulas are based on the standard Fourier coefficient formulas for the "true" Fourier coefficients $a_na^n$ and $b_na^n$, where then the power of $a$ is transferred to the other side.

Comment: @LutzLehmann If the function f(x) is not even, can I not just restrict f(x) first to be in the domain from 0 to L, and then do an "even extension" of f(x)? i.e. define f(x) = f(-x) when $ 
-L<x<0$? and then still use that formula that I have above to get $a_n$? Can I do that? I thought I was taught something about "even extension" and "odd extension" in class. So that formula is still valid to use right?

Comment: Yes, that is the motivation behind the cosine series. But the function you get from that is in general different from the original $f$ on $[-L,0)$. For a general function on $[-L,L]$ and periodic you need all function values to determine the coefficients. You could of course compute the sine series for the odd and the cosine series for the even part of $f$ separately.